# .htaccess 301 redirect issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2

I need 301 redirect from example.com to www.example.com. This is working solution, but when 
I paste it in whole .htaccess site go down.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Rest .htaccess file

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
php_flag magic_quotes_runtime off
php_flag register_globals off

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^.htaccess$ - [F]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [L]
Options -Indexes
AddDefaultCharset windows-1251
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(service|news|search|project)/?$ index.php?menu=$1
RewriteRule ^error/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?menu=error&loadinfo=$1
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?menu=page&loadinfo=$1
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?menu=news&loadinfo=$1
RewriteRule ^news/page-([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?menu=news&page=$1
RewriteRule ^service/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?menu=service&category=$1
RewriteRule ^service/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?menu=service&category=$1&loadinfo=$2
RewriteRule ^project/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?menu=project&loadinfo=$1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whats the `AllowOverride` value of the folder where you have your .htaccess? Your `DocumentRoot` (or `VirtualHost`) specification needs to be set to at least `AllowOverride Options` in order to allow `php_flag` within .htaccess files.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```